# Express Gateway (key-auth enabled) giving CORs issue when called from front-end application

Tags: node.js, nginx, cors, express-gateway

**Issue with description**

I have my front end application developed and deployed using Angular and nginx respectively.

Resource server is developed using No stress NodeJS.

Flow is

```
UI -> express gateway -> resource server
```

Whenever trying to call an **API from UI**, with ***key-auth enabled*** in express gateway, getting error

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://ip:port/api/function_name' from origin 'http://url' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

```
Same API when called from Postman works though. It also works if I remove 'key-auth' from gateway.
```

Sharing the code changes done at various levels:

**Code - *Express Gateway***

```yaml
example:
    apiEndpoints:
      - example
    policies:
      - cors:
          - action:
              origin: ["*"]
              methods: "HEAD,GET,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS"
              preflightContinue: true
              optionsSuccessStatus: 204
              maxAge: 600
              allowedHeaders:
                [
                  "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization",
                ]
      - key-auth:
          - condition:
              name: not
              condition:
                  name: method
                  methods:
                    - OPTIONS
      - proxy:
          - action:
              serviceEndpoint: exampleService
              proxyTimeout: 0
```

**Code - *Angular***

```js
const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'Application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        'Authorization': "Bearer " + apiKey,
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    }),
};
```

**Code - *Resource Server - routes.js***

```js
export default function routes(app) {
   app.use(cors());
   // Also tried setting res.setHeader explicitly, but no success.
}
```

**Code - *nginx level***

```sh
server(){
   ...
   location / {
        # Simple Requests
        if ($request_method ~* "(GET|POST)") {
             add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"  *;
        }

        # Preflighted requests
        if ($request_method = OPTIONS ) {
             add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"  *;
             add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" "GET, POST, OPTIONS, HEAD";
             add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" "Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept";
             return 200;
        }

        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
   }
}
```

I have gone through various links on this issue, tried multiple things as shown above but couldn't find any solution, thus raising new one.

How to remove this CORs error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue after making below corrections/changes:

**Code - *Angular***  (Replaced Bearer with apiKey)

```js
const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'Application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        'Authorization': "apiKey " + apiKey,
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    }),
};
```

**Code - *nginx level***  (Modified the condition in location function)

```
server {
        ....
        location / {
            if ($request_method = OPTIONS) {
                return 204;
            }
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
            add_header Access-Control-Max-Age 3600;
            add_header Access-Control-Expose-Headers Content-Length;
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers Range;
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

Everything else remains same.

Answer (score 0):

also helpful to solve the issue for jwt verification at gateway